# How to write data column by column into a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I am having an issue, I am trying to achieve the format below in the csv file:

```
client connections   |          | node repsonse time
```

However, there is not a list of data here, it will be just a single row of data, no repeating rows or data, etc.

However when I run my code it only puts the code into a single cell, rather than spread it across the columns correctly.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
with open("expirement_node_descovery.csv","a") as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows((client_connections, '', average_getAdrr_no_node_response))
```

Comment: try `writer.writerow([a for a in (client_connections, '', average_getAdrr_no_node_response)])`

Comment: @Tehscript - no need to create a new list, `writer.writerow((client_connections, '', average_getAdrr_no_node_response))` works.

Comment: I think it would be very easy to turn this into a working example. Can you do that so we can run ti?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because in the line `writer.writerows((client_connections, '', average_getAdrr_no_node_response))` you are not writing a list, but a tuple consisting of 3 items. In that case it might be writing all three things into a single cell.

Instead try `writer.writerows([client_connections, '', average_getAdrr_no_node_response])`

Can you give us an example of `client_connections` and `average_getAdrr_no_node_response`?